# Minion Voice in Adobe Audition

Tags: audio, voice-manipulation, adobe-audition

How to manipulate a voice to match like **Minion** using **Adobe Audition**?

Answer (score 1):

A bit of [pitch](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/companion-videos-for-inspire/adobe-audition-cc-correcting-the-timing-and-pitch/) I guess, the rest is acting an a strange language.

Comment: Actually, this is the co-director Pierre Coffin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Coffin that acts the minion's voices worldwide !